# Are there any example of reversible open system?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

I went through different formulaes of work done under different system. the work done were for reversible system open and closed. Are there any reversible open system?

Answer (score 1):

An open system is one that permits mass to cross the system boundary. The diagram below is a generic example of an open system.

With appropriate simplifications this generic system can be a component of a 2 phase power cycle, such as the turbine, pump, condenser, or boiler of a reversible Rankine steam cycle.

For example, if $Q_{in}=0$ (adiabatic), and there are no changes in kinetic or potential energy of the fluid entering and exiting the system ($V_{e}=V_{i}$ and $h_{e}=h_{o}$), and there is steady flow rate ($m_{e}=m_{i}$), steam is the working fluid, and if the process is carried out reversibly, the generic system below can represent a reversible adiabatic turbine of a Rankine cycle.

Then the equation for reversible turbine work (power) depends only on the entering and exiting enthalpies and flow rate, and becomes

$$\dot W_{out}=\dot m(h_{i}-h_{es})$$

Where the $s$ in $h_{es}$ denotes a constant entropy (reversible adiabatic, or isentropic) turbine.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: The equation you gave is also the equation for an irreversible turbine operating at steady state.  For the turbine to be operating adiabatically and reversibly, the entropy per unit mass of the exit stream must be equal to the entropy per unit mass of the entering stream.

Comment: @ChetMiller Look at the last sentence of my answer. I stated the exiting enthalpy is that for an isentropic (reversible adiabatic) turbine. Isn't that the same thing as saying  the entropy per unit mass of the exit steam equals that of the entering steam. Aren't we saying the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but the same equation applies to an adiabatic irreversible turbine.  I think it is important to point out that the entropy change for the stream is zero for the reversible limit.  Don't you think it would be worthwhile to explicitly include that in your answer?

Comment: @ChetMiller I am revising the equation to use $h_{es}$ where the "s" typically is used to designate isentropic process.